# Reporting cumulative coverage across multiple Python versions

Tags: python, coverage.py, tox, python-coverage

I have code that runs conditionally depending on the current version of Python, because I'm supporting 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3 from the same package.

I currently generate a coverage report like this, using the default version of Python:

```
coverage run --source mypackage setup.py test
coverage report -m
coverage html
```

This is useful but not ideal, as it only reports coverage on Python 2.7. Instead, I would like to generate a **cumulative report** of the test coverage across 2.6, 2.7, **and** 3.2.

How do I generate a multi-version coverage report?

Side note: I've tried putting `commands = coverage run --source mypackage setup.py test` into my tox.ini for each of py26, py27, py33, but that doesn't seem to generate a cumulative coverage report.

Comment: I doubt it, since there's a different version of coverage for each version of Python. I suggest you contact [Ned](http://nedbatchelder.com/site/aboutned.html) and see what he suggests. It's also hard to imagine what such a cumulative coverage report might look like -- other than just being the reports from the different versions concatenated together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html#cmd-combining is of use according to the developer.

Comment: Please add the gist of it - the link might break at some point

Comment: @MartinThoma the command is `coverage combine`. If the link breaks, the command might too.

Comment: The link is dead.